# Aliasing Column with Hashtag in Name in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alias, sequel

I have a legacy database with a column named similar to `My#Column` which I am trying to alias. In my Sequel model I have:

```
alias_attribute :MyColumn, :"My#Column"
```

But I get a syntax error:

`...Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end`

The problem seems to be the `#`. I have tried escaping it like `\#` but I get the same error. I don't understand why I get a syntax error as this kind of symbol has worked for me in other places.

What do I do to get this alias to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `alias_attribute` is actually doing [Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb#L21)

```
  module_eval <<-STR, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
    def #{new_name}; self.#{old_name}; end          # def subject; self.title; end
    def #{new_name}?; self.#{old_name}?; end        # def subject?; self.title?; end
    def #{new_name}=(v); self.#{old_name} = v; end  # def subject=(v); self.title = v; end
  STR
```

So essentially this is becoming

```
  def MyColumn; self.My#Column; end
  def MyColumn?; self.My#Column?; end
  def MyColumn=(val); self.My#Column= val; end
```

Notice the fact that this is in a single line which means that everything after `self.My` becomes a comment (including the `end`) and thus the error you are receiving. Even if this was not a single line in `rails` `ruby` would simply raise a `NoMethodError` for the fact that `My` is not a method because the `#Column` portion would be treated as a comment.

This also seems strange since `ActiveModel#alias_attribute` has a functional implementation of the exact same via [`define_proxy_call`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb#L365) which looks like

```
def define_proxy_call(include_private, mod, name, send, *extra)
  defn = if NAME_COMPILABLE_REGEXP.match?(name)
     "def #{name}(*args)"
  else
     "define_method(:'#{name}') do |*args|"
  end

  extra = (extra.map!(&:inspect) << "*args").join(", ".freeze)

  target = if CALL_COMPILABLE_REGEXP.match?(send)
    "#{"self." unless include_private}#{send}(#{extra})"
  else
    "send(:'#{send}', #{extra})"
  end

  mod.module_eval <<-RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
    #{defn}
      #{target}
    end
    RUBY
end
```

Here you can see it actually checks to see if the new name(`name`) and original name(`send`) are "compilable" and if not it handles them appropriately.

Rather than `alias_attribute` which is going to have issues with what is essentially a comment character. I would suggest manually implementing the same using `public_send` e.g.

```
  def MyColumn
    self.public_send("My#Column") 
  end 
  def MyColumn=(val)
    self.public_send("My#Column=",val)
  end
  def MyColumn?
    self.public_send("My#Column?")
  end
```

This should result in the same but without the syntax issues.

Comment: Thank you for the taking the time to explain this. I have learnt a thing or two. And it worked. Cheers!